# PHP form going to different e-mail addresses depending on drop down selection

Tags: php, forms, email

so I basically have zero experience using PHP, and I need to create a PHP form, that depending on the users' selection, will go to different e-mail addresses.

For example the drop down would have options like: Service, Parts, Human Resources, etc.

And each of those options, when selected, will allow the entire submission of "name, email, phone number, etc." to go to that particular department's e-mail address.

I saw a few answers for things similar to this, but with my limited knowledge of PHP, I am having a lot of trouble creating this.

Could anyone help me out please??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question? What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

you could get the value of the email from your select field and use it when sending the mail
like this:

```
$mail['to'] = $_POST['mail']; 
//make sure to filter this using regex/etc.. 
//to make sure this is a valid email and is coming from your own form.

mail($mail['to'], $mail['subject'], $mail['body'], $mail['headers'])
```

i'll leave the filtering of the data to you, but you should get the idea.

EDIT:

make sure that you filter `$_POST['mail'];` because if you did not, this would result from other people submitting emails to your script which is a huge security vulnerability.
possible solutions are using nonce or 1 time use tokens etc.
try searching up for **mail header injection** for more info.

Comment: You're passing data from POST directly into `mail()`. That's really not a good idea.

Comment: i explicitly said this on my post: "i'll leave the filtering of the data to you, but you should get the idea.". thanks for the downvote. ;)

Comment: You did indeed mention it. But your code as it's written has a huge security hole in it. The question explicitly states that she's only got limited knowledge of PHP - if you can add something to explain why she needs to filter the email, it'll make this a better answer.

Comment: thanks. will try to make sure all aspects get explained next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mail()` function and choose an appropriate email address based on posted params. Note that allowing unknown users to directly send mails through your server is probably not a great idea: what if there is a security hole in how `mail()` is implemented? Why don't you put the relative email addresses on the website and show only the right one depending on what entry user selected from the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
<?php
// Check if form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST["dep"])) {
if ($_POST["dep"] == 1) {
$email = "sales@example.com";
}
elseif ($_POST["dep"] == 2) {
$email = "support@example.com";
}
// Send the email
mail($email, "The subject", "The Body, "Some headers (optional)")
}
?>
<select name="dep">
<optoin value="1">Sales</option>
<optoin value="2">Support</option>
</select>
```